# JavaScript Array remove begin the begin quotes and end quotes in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to Build an array that displays value, color, highlight and label in an array.

The hard code array looks like this:

```js
var data = [
    {
      value: 300,
      color:"#F7464A",
      highlight: "#FF5A5E",
      label: "Red"
    },
    {
      value: 50,
      color: "#46BFBD",
      highlight: "#5AD3D1",
      label: "Green"
    },
    {
      value: 100,
      color: "#FDB45C",
      highlight: "#FFC870",
      label: "Yellow"
    }
];
```

Here is my code:

```
var pieData = [];
var label = [];
var beginData = "{";
var endData = "}";
var firstItem = "value:";
var secondItem = "color:";
var thirdItem = "highlight:";
var fourItem = "label:";
var spaceItem = ",";
var beginQuote = '"';
var endQuote =  '"';
var checkCounter = x.childElementCount -1;
var arrayColor = ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#466abf", "#dc46f7", "#46bf8b", "#afbf46", "#bf8b46", "#bf5c46", "#b7bf46", "#46a9bf", "#bf4846" ];
var array = [     '#FF5A5E', '#5AD3D1', '#FFC870', '#466abf', '#dc46f7', '#46bf8b', '#afbf46', '#bf8b46', '#bf5c46', '#b7bf46', "#46a9bf", "#bf4846" ];
for( i = 0; i < x.childElementCount; i++) {
    name = x.childNodes[i].attributes.name.value;
    value = x.childNodes[i].attributes.value.value;
    array[i];
    arrayColor[i];
    if (checkCounter != i){
       pieData.push(beginData + firstItem + beginQuote + value + endQuote + spaceItem + secondItem + beginQuote + array[i] + endQuote + spaceItem + thirdItem + beginQuote + arrayColor[i]+ endQuote + spaceItem + fourItem + beginQuote + name + endQuote +  endData + spaceItem);
    }
     else{
        pieData.push(beginData + firstItem + beginQuote + value + endQuote + spaceItem + secondItem + beginQuote + array[i] + endQuote + spaceItem + thirdItem + beginQuote + arrayColor[i]+ endQuote + spaceItem + fourItem + beginQuote + name + endQuote +  endData);

                            }
  label.push(name);
```

my output is :

```
  0: "{value:"40",color:"#FF5A5E",highlight:"#F7464A",label:"Abnormal First Mam"},"
  1: "{value:"17",color:"#5AD3D1",highlight:"#46BFBD",label:"Abnormal Rescreen Mam"},"
  2: "{value:"57",color:"#FFC870",highlight:"#FDB45C",label:"Abnormal Total Mam"},"
  3: "{value:"5",color:"#466abf",highlight:"#466abf",label:"Abnormal CBE (Norm Mam)"},"
  4: "{value:"0",color:"#dc46f7",highlight:"#dc46f7",label:"Assessment Inc. Mam"},"
  5: "{value:"0",color:"#46bf8b",highlight:"#46bf8b",label:"Film Comp. req. Mam"}"
```

Comment: Do you want to create an array of objects or an array of strings?

Comment: use `JSON.parse` to convert the string to an object.

Comment: You have undefined variables in your code (what is `x` and its properties ...?). Also, your code has lines that don't do anything, like `array[i];`. What did you intend to do there? It looks like you reference some HTML in your code? What is the HTML and what role does it play in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is building strings, not objects. You should use the object literal syntax to build objects in your loop. Assuming that `x.childNodes` is array-like, you can use this code:

```
var arrayColor = ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#466abf", "#dc46f7", "#46bf8b", "#afbf46", "#bf8b46", "#bf5c46", "#b7bf46", "#46a9bf", "#bf4846" ];
var array = [     '#FF5A5E', '#5AD3D1', '#FFC870', '#466abf', '#dc46f7', '#46bf8b', '#afbf46', '#bf8b46', '#bf5c46', '#b7bf46', "#46a9bf", "#bf4846" ];

var pieData = Array.from(x.childNodes, ({attributes:{value, name}}, i) => ({
    value: value.value,
    color: arrayColor[i % arrayColor.length],
    highlight: array[i % array.length],
    label: name.value,
}));

console.log(pieData);
```

The `%` is used to avoid that you go out of range of your color arrays -- in case there are more `childNodes` entries than you have in your arrays.

`Array.from` is ideal for mapping array-like objects (like `childNodes`) to an array with derived data, which is exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I need to move my colors for the pie chart to the attributes.  I was making it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying about chart and attributes. From your question I understood you had a certain output in mind, an array with objects. I believe my answer produces that array with objects. Does it not answer your question?

Comment: Yes you answered my question. I am now seeing in the console.log <set name: "Bob" value='40' color='#F7464A' highlight = '#FF5A5E"></set.